# With styled-components, how can I target a child class of a component?

Tags: css, material-ui, styled-components

I'm using a `mui` Badge component and I want to style the little circle. I have:

```
const BadgeStyled = styled(Badge)`
  & > .muibadge-badge: {
    background-color: #d3d4d7;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  }
`;
```

The generated HTML is:

```
    <span class="MuiBadge-root BaseBadge-root css-1o9b3gb-MuiBadge-root">
    ... some stuff
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</button>
<div class="MuiAvatar-root MuiAvatar-circular MuiAvatar-colorDefault css-f84387-MuiAvatar-root">
   <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-eyebrowSmall css-1bcwatu-MuiTypography-root">J</span>
</div>
<span class="MuiBadge-badge MuiBadge-standard MuiBadge-anchorOriginTopRight MuiBadge-anchorOriginTopRightRectangular MuiBadge-overlapRectangular MuiBadge-colorPrimary BaseBadge-badge css-1es1533-MuiBadge-badge">4</span>
</span>
```

So I have `MuiBadge-badge` in the generated HTML, but my style doesn't seem to apply. Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, have a look at this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-sky-20loib?file=/demo.tsx)

Here is how you can style the Badge component

```
const BadgeStyled = styled(Badge)({
  "& .MuiBadge-badge": {
    backgroundColor: "#d3d4d7",
    width: '15px',
    height: '15px',
  }
});
```